# How to remove every multiple of 2 element in a vector by index

Tags: c++, vector, erase

I am trying to remove every 2nd element from an integer vector in C++

```
int n = 10001;    
std::vector<int> sieve;    

for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i)
    sieve.push_back(i);


for (int i = 2; i < sieve.size(); i += 2)
    sieve.erase(sieve.begin() + i);
```

I want to remove every 2nd element from the vector ( which would be multiples of 2 in range from 2-10001). The output is this:

```
// index, value
0 2
1 3
2 5
3 6
4 8
5 9
6 11
7 12
8 14
9 15
10 17
....
```

So it removes the 4, 10, and 16 as expected. However there are still many multiples of 2 still in there, ie 6, 8, 12, 14

EDIT Solved using method @Retired Ninja posted in comments. (Do it in reverse)

```
for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    sieve.push_back(i);

for (int i = sieve.size(); i >= p; i -= p)
    sieve.erase(sieve.end() - i);
```

Comment: Think about what happens to the indices of each element once you start deleting elements.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh... it updates the indices every pass. What would be the approach then?

Comment: Do it in reverse.

Comment: Or just make a new vector, move over every other element, them move the new container back on top of the first one. **Way** fewer assignments. Or do something like `std::partition` so you only have one array resize operation, which is also made trivial by being at the end.

Comment: Or maybe try something like increase the number of elements that you skip by 1 every time you delete an element.

Comment: Are you trying to make Euclid's sieve?

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez Yes. I am trying to make Euclid's sieve. My initial idea after realizing how the indices updated was to set the values to I want to 0 and then remove all zeros from the vector. But now I am going to use the reverse method Retired Ninja mentioned.

Comment: Notice that way of removal will not work to remove multiple of 3 then (as you already remove multiples of 2). idea is to "flag" numbers (so you can indeed do simple loop with increment of p). if you remove element, you then need to check if number is divisible by p before remove it (so you can use [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom), but it is no longer Euclid's sieve)

Answer (score 2):

When you are erasing second element the iterator of next element decrease 1. 
So increasing 1 time of loop variable is ok.

```
int n = 100;    
std::vector<int> sieve;    

for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i)
    sieve.push_back(i);


for (int i = 2; i < sieve.size(); i += 1)
    sieve.erase(sieve.begin() + i);
```

And another way in case of erasing pth element:

```
    int cnt=0;
    int l=sieve.size();
    for (int i = 2; i < l; i += p){
        sieve.erase(sieve.begin() + (i-cnt));
            cnt++;
    }
```

Comment: While this approach works for every 2nd (which I did ask for) it doesn't scale well I think, for example if I wanted to then erase every 3rd element

Comment: @GrahamChapman Added another approach to delete pth element .

Answer (score 0):

How about this? This removes every `nth` element starting at `start` from `vec`.

It's performed in-place, involves only a single array resize, and each element not erased is moved exactly once.

```
void remove(std::size_t nth, std::size_t start, std::vector<int> &vec)
{
    std::size_t step;
    for (step = 1; start < vec.size(); ++step, start += nth)
    {
        for (std::size_t i = 1; i < nth && start + i < vec.size(); ++i)
        {
            vec[start + i - step] = vec[start + i];
        }
    }
    vec.resize(vec.size() - (step - 1));
}
```